# [react,ES6]I fail to access object in http script label in index.html , from my own JS page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**This is the script in my index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://api.map.baidu.com/api v=2.0&ak=eBGR7XzaPhB5UbYARl3E7ksdkMdgrCw7"></script>
```

and  I try to access a object --"BMap" from the script in my JS page which look like this:

```
var map = new BMap.Map("allmap");    // 创建Map实例
```

then I get error:"`error! BMap is not defined`"

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you wanted to use BMap that is provided by baidu api. I changed the src that is actually pointing to the script and it seems to work. Note that you probably want to change the `https` to `http` when you are developing locally, as it may not work otherwise. See working example below (I had to use https because stackoverflow uses it by default).

If you have any other js module that uses `BMap`, make sure that it is called **after** the baidu api script is declared. S

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.map.baidu.com/getscript?v=1.1&ak=&services=true&t=20130716024058"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../path/test.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../otherpath/someOtherjs.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
        // You can use BMap here...
        console.log(BMap);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help! but  what troubles me is not the src of the script.   the problem is that I try to use BMap in another JS moudle(not the index.html in your example)    for example:

Comment: for example, this is  my "another js moudle", which call test.js ,and try to use   BMap in the test.js, not in the index.html

Comment: in this way, I try to console.log(BMap) but get an undefined error